# How to XOR two strings in python that produces only ENGLISH ALPHABETS?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a beginner in python and somehow managed to create code for One Time Pad Encryption. But instead of special characters/symbols, i need the result to be in alphabets only.

```
import random
import string
plain=raw_input("Enter PlainText: ")
length=len(plain)
key = "".join(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") for i in range(length))
print "RANDOM KEY GENERATED: ",key

message=str(plain)
key1=str(key)
print "STRING 1",message
print "STRING 2",key1

arr1 = bytearray(message, 'utf-8')
print "ARRAY 1 : ",arr1

arr2 = bytearray(key, 'utf-8')
print "ARRAY 2 : ",arr2

b = bytearray(len(arr1))
for i in range(len(arr1)):
   b[i] = arr1[i] ^ arr2[i]

xored=list(b)
print "XORED LIST: ",xored

mystring=""
for char in xored:
   mystring=mystring+chr(char)
print "CIPHER TEXT IS: ",mystring
```

[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fomdh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **chr() Parameters:** The `chr()` method takes a single parameter, an integer `i`.
>
> **chr() returns:** a character (a string) whose Unicode code point is the integer i

You just need to replace `mystring=mystring+chr(char)` with `mystring=mystring+str(char)`.

Here is your fixed code:

```
import random
import string

plain=raw_input("Enter PlainText: ")
length=len(plain)
key = "".join(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") for i in range(length))
print "RANDOM KEY GENERATED: ",key

message=str(plain)
key1=str(key)
print "STRING 1",message
print "STRING 2",key1

arr1 = bytearray(message, 'utf-8')
print "ARRAY 1 : ",arr1

arr2 = bytearray(key, 'utf-8')
print "ARRAY 2 : ",arr2

b = bytearray(len(arr1))
for i in range(len(arr1)):
   b[i] = arr1[i] ^ arr2[i]

xored=list(b)
print "XORED LIST: ",xored

mystring=""
for char in xored:
   mystring=mystring+str(char)
print "CIPHER TEXT IS: ",mystring
```

Which outputs:

```
Enter PlainText: Foo
RANDOM KEY GENERATED:  dAD
STRING 1 Foo
STRING 2 dAD
ARRAY 1 :  Foo
ARRAY 2 :  dAD
XORED LIST:  [34, 46, 43]
CIPHER TEXT IS:  344643
```

Comment: Thank you Alan B. It's exactly what I wanted.